# WSO2 EMM, how to get iOS Component or sign CSR by myself?

Tags: ios, wso2, mdm

I am trying with my team to setup a Mobile Device Management tool, but I need some help for the open source one : WSO2 EMM

I have followed offical documentation : https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Generating+a+MDM+APNS+Certificate

But when I try to get a Signed CSR file via their website, I get no answer : http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/csr/
It seems to be a mandatory step, I found some messages which said that "By default EMM does not ship iOS components"

Actually, like some others, I get error "500: Something has gone wrong", with following log error

```
[2015-09-08 04:17:37,443] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13) (/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag#2)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage org.wso2.carbon.emm.ios.core.service.iOSMobilityManagerService] is not a function, it is object. (/emm/modules/iosemm.js#13) (/emm/ios_utils/ca.jag#2)
```

So my question is how to get these iOS components ? or how to sign the csr by myself ?

Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

You might have to wait. You cannot get iOS to work without support of an MDM vendor. You need to get CSR signed by WSO2 or any other MDM vendor and WSO2 iOS components from WSO2. Or you can contact WSO2 directly and ask for help.

http://wso2.com/contact